# Extracting inner value on CDATA with Linq to XML using a filter

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I am using this code to retrieve the values I want from XML:

```
IEnumerable<ForewordReview> reviews = null;
try
{
    reviews = from item in xmlDoc.Descendants("node")
              select new ForewordReview()
              {
                  PubDate = item.Element("created").ToString(),
                  Isbn = item.Element("isbn").ToString(),
                  Summary = item.Element("review").ToString()
              };
} // ...
```

Incidentally, a client is now passing us almost every tag with CDATA which I need to extract:

```
<review>
    <node>
        <created>
            <![CDATA[2012-01-23 12:40:57]]>
        </created>
        <isbn>
            <![CDATA[123456789]]>
        </isbn>
        <summary>
            <![CDATA[Teh Kittehs like to play in teh mud]]>
        </summary>
    </node>
</review>
```

I have seen a couple of solutions for extracting these values from within the CDATA tag, one of which is to use a where clause on the LINQ statement:

```
where element.NodeType == System.Xml.XmlNodeType.CDATA
```

I sort of see whats going on here, but I am not sure this works with how I am using Linq (specifically, building an object from selected items.

Do I need to apply this filter on the items in the select statement individually? Otherwise, I dont really understand how this will work with the code I am using.

As always, I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Cast each `XElement` to a `string` instead](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff986933.aspx):

```
reviews = from item in xmlDoc.Descendants("node")
          select new 
          {
              PubDate = (string)item.Element("created"),
              Isbn = (string)item.Element("isbn"),
              Summary = (string)item.Element("summary")
          };
// Output:
// {
//      PubDate = 2012-01-23 12:40:57,
//      Isbn = 123456789,
//      Summary = Teh Kittehs like to play in teh mud
// }
```

This also works with other data types, such as `int`, `float`, `DateTime`, etc:

```
reviews = from item in xmlDoc.Descendants("node")
          select new 
          {
              PubDate = (DateTime)item.Element("created")
          };
// Output:
// {
//      PubDate = 1/23/2012 12:40:57
// }
```

[It also works with `XAttribute`s as well](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff986944.aspx).

Comment: Because `XNode.ToString` *"[r]eturns the indented XML for this node,"* [per MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341005.aspx). Whereas the explicit casts provide the ability to retrieve the, *"concatenated string value of all of the element's text and descendant's text,"* [per MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb155263.aspx).

Comment: Thank you for your most thorough help. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

Remember that there is no difference between the meaning of:

```
<a>
 <b>Hello</b>
 <c>&amp; hello again</c>
</a>
```

and of

```
<a>
 <b><![CDATA[Hello]]></b>
 <c><![CDATA[& hello again]]></c>
</a>
```

Since you're calling `ToString()` and getting the entire content back - opening and closing tags, entity references, etc. still in XML form, then you must be prepared to deal with it in XML form. If not, the problem isn't with the code you show here, it's with the code that was okay with `PubDate` being `"<created>2012-01-23 12:40:57</created>"` and now 
isn't okay with it being the exactly equivalent "";

Either change that code to really parse the XML (for which the framework offers lots of things to help), or change it to take the date on its own and use `Element("created").Value` to retrieve it.

Comment: Ah, thank you for this as well. I did notice in debug it seemed to grab the whole tag - hence the "To String". +1 for the added elaboration.

Comment: NP. sixlettervariables got in before me with another way of doing the same thing and for the same reason, but it never hurts to have added a slightly different explanation.

Comment: It certainly doesn't hurt. You, on the other hand, did a bit more with your explanation. Your statement "Change the code to really parse the XML", made me really think about what I was doing with my above code. Thanks again.